# Euclidean fermion propagator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, wick-rotation

I want to write the fermion propagator
$$
i\dfrac{p^\mu\gamma_\mu+m}{p^2-m^2}
$$
in Euclidean space.

In Minkowski, the conventions are $g^{\mu\nu}=\{+,-,-,-\}$; $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu = 2g^{\mu\nu}$.

To my understanding, what happens is $x_0 \to - i x_4$, so $p^2\to-p_E^2$ (where $p_E^2>0$).

Assume I define the Euclidean gamma matrices in the same way as $4$-vectors,
i.e. by introducing $\gamma^0 = i \gamma^4$:
$$\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu = -2\delta^{\mu\nu}\quad\text{(Euclidean)}$$
But what is happening to $p^\mu\gamma_\mu$? Do I get the minus as well?
$$
i\dfrac{p^\mu\gamma_\mu+m}{p^2-m^2} \to 
i\dfrac{-p^\mu\gamma_\mu+m}{-p_E^2-m^2} =i\dfrac{p^\mu\gamma_\mu-m}{p_E^2+m^2}
$$

Comment: Hint: write down the free Dirac equation in the Euclidean signature; extract the differential operator $D$ such that the classical equation of motion is given by $D\psi = 0$. The propagator is then given by $D_x W(x, y) = i \delta^{(4)}(x - y)$. It is an exceptionally simple computation, which involves casting this differential equation to the algebraic form in the Fourier space (by substituting $\partial_{\mu} \rightarrow i p_{\mu}$) and inverting the matrix $\tilde{D}$.

Comment: The expression for the propagator is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9403224